# Function ascontiguousarray returns different strides in NumPy 1.11.1 and 1.13.1

Tags: python, numpy

I am having a issue with function ascontiguousarray() that returns different strides in NumPy 1.11.1 and 1.13.1.

Code to reproduce (Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7.12):

```
import os
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16]],dtype='uint32')
x = x.T
x = np.ascontiguousarray(x)
print(x.strides)
```

In NumPy 1.11.1 it returns strides: (64, 4) (correct strides in my opinion)

In NumPy 1.13.1 it returns strides: (4, 4) (unexpected strides)

Thank you for all the help in explanation or solution.

Comment: Well I think `x` is a view of the memory where we had the original array initialized. That might have something to do with it. What should be the correct strides or why that discrepancy between versions? - Not sure really.

Comment: Interesting.  In this case, if you execute `y = x.T; z = np.ascontiguousarray(y)` and then check `z is y`, the result is `True`: they are exactly the same object (not just views of the same data).  The strides of `x` are (4, 4), and the transpose of `x` just flips the strides, so `y` has the same strides as `x`.  In numpy 1.6.2 (the only older version that I have handy), `y.flags` shows `False` for `C_CONTIGUOUS`, but in 1.13.1, `y.flags` shows `C_CONTIGUOUS` is `True`.  *That* appears to be the underlying change that matters here.  To answer your question, we'd have to know why that changed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `order` explains this unexpected strides  (`(4,4)`).

An ordinary column array:

```
In [289]: np.ones((3,1),int).strides
Out[289]: (4, 4)
```

An ordinary row array:

```
In [290]: np.ones((1,3),int).strides
Out[290]: (12, 4)
```

But change the row array to order `F`, and strides become like the column array:

```
In [291]: np.ones((1,3),int,order='F').strides
Out[291]: (4, 4)
```

The transpose is `F_contiguous`, and has the same strides as the order `F` array:

```
In [292]: np.ones((3,1),int).T.flags
Out[292]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
In [293]: np.ones((3,1),int).T.strides
Out[293]: (4, 4)
```

(`np.ones((3,1),int)` is also dually contiguous, because one dimension is size 1).

If I force the transpose to `C` order, the strides change:

```
In [305]: np.ones((3,1),int).T.copy(order='C').strides
Out[305]: (12, 4)
```

The column array with order `F`:

```
In [312]: np.ones((3,1),int,order='F').strides
Out[312]: (4, 12)
```

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. Do you have any workaround ? My workaround is to force C order with x = np.array(x, order='C') after x = np.ascontiguousarray(x)

Comment: What's wrong with (4,4)? How are you using `strides`?

Comment: This is a part of a larger system. We are expecting a size of strides from NumPy 1.11.1

Comment: I think the (64,4) from 1.11.1 is actually wrong, though it is tricky to visualize the correct strides with `F` order.  Cf. `Out[289]` with `Out[291]`. 
 Practically it doesn't matter whether the first stride is 64 or 4.  That shape is 1, so it never has to step that way.  A work around is the ignore the first strides value.